# Using column name as a new attribute in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I have the following data structure

```
Date         Agric  Food 
01/01/1990    1.3   0.9  
01/02/1990    1.2   0.9
```

I would like to covert it into the format

```
Date        Sector  Beta
01/01/1990  Agric   1.3
01/02/1990  Agric   1.2
01/01/1990  Food    0.9
01/02/1990  Food    0.9
```

while I am sure I can do this in a complicated way, is there a way of doing this in a few line of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [**`pd.DataFrame.melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)

```
df.melt('Date', var_name='Sector', value_name='Beta')

         Date Sector  Beta
0  01/01/1990  Agric   1.3
1  01/02/1990  Agric   1.2
2  01/01/1990   Food   0.9
3  01/02/1990   Food   0.9
```

Comment: quick question: you used df.melt, but the link you added is pd.melt(), are they equivalent?

Comment: They are equivalent.  In `pandas 0.20` then turned `pd.melt` into a `pd.DataFrame` method.  I mixed up the links.  I fixed the links but they are equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

Use `set_index` and `stack`:

```
df.set_index('Date').rename_axis('Sector',axis=1).stack()\
  .reset_index(name='Beta')
```

Output:

```
         Date Sector  Beta
0  01/01/1990  Agric   1.3
1  01/01/1990   Food   0.9
2  01/02/1990  Agric   1.2
3  01/02/1990   Food   0.9
```

Comment: Nice `stack`~:)

Answer (score 4):

Or you can using `lreshape`

```
df=pd.lreshape(df2, {'Date': ["Date","Date"], 'Beta': ['Agric', 'Food']})
df['Sector']=sorted(df2.columns.tolist()[1:3]*2)

   Out[654]: 
         Date  Beta Sector
0  01/01/1990   1.3  Agric
1  01/02/1990   1.2  Agric
2  01/01/1990   0.9   Food
3  01/02/1990   0.9   Food
```

In case you have 48 columns

```
df=pd.lreshape(df2, {'Date':['Date']*2, 'Beta': df2.columns.tolist()[1:3]})
df['Sector']=sorted(df2.columns.tolist()[1:3]*2)
```

also for the columns Sector , it is more safety create it by

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, 2) for x in df2.columns.tolist()[1:3]))
```

EDIT Cause `lreshap` is undocumented (As per@ Ted Petrou ***It's best to use available DataFrame methods if possible and then if none available use documented functions. pandas is constantly looking to improve its API and calling undocumented, old and experimental functions like lreshape for anything is unwarranted. Furthermore, this problem is a very straightforward usecase for melt or stack. It is a bad precedent to set for those new to pandas to come to Stack Overflow and find upvoted answers with lreshape.*** )

Also , if you want to know more about this , you can check it at [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15003)

Below are the method by using `pd.wide_to_long`

```
dict1 = {'Agric':'A_Agric','Food':'A_Food'}
df2 = df.rename(columns=dict1)
pd.wide_to_long(df2.reset_index(),['A'],i='Date',j='Sector',sep='_',suffix='.').reset_index().drop('index',axis=1).rename(columns={'A':'Beta '})

Out[2149]: 
         Date Sector  Beta 
0  01/01/1990  Agric    1.3
1  01/02/1990  Agric    1.2
2  01/01/1990   Food    0.9
3  01/02/1990   Food    0.9
```

Comment: my only concern with this is that I have 48 columns in the real data. :)

Comment: then , you can using `df.columns.tolist()`, one sec , I will edited it

Comment: @Lost1 Edited ~

Comment: It's best to use available DataFrame methods if possible and then if none available use documented functions. pandas is constantly looking to improve its API and calling undocumented, old and experimental functions like `lreshape` for anything is unwarranted. Furthermore, this problem is a very straightforward usecase for melt or stack. It is a bad precedent to set for those new to pandas to come to Stack Overflow and find upvoted answers with `lreshape`. Stack overflow has unfortunately encouraged the spread and usage of the awful `.ix` indexing operator in this same manner.

Comment: @TedPetrou kind of agree btw, if you can post the problem you mention about  `lreshape` in github  will much appreciate

Comment: @wen I have [posted it on github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15003). Hopefully `lreshape` gets deprecated.

Comment: @TedPetrou BTW updated my answer ~ and pointed out the `lreshape` is no safety at all . Thank you for the correction ~ :)

Comment: @wen Well done on the update. downvote removed though 'wide_to_long` is overkill here.

Comment: @TedPetrou You are right,`wide_to_long` is bad for this situation ~  I updated here (rather than deleted) just make sure any SO user who review the question notice that `lreshape` can be replaced by a documented function