# how to split and concat pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a `datetime` index DataFrame of pandas like this:

```
                         A   B  C  A_1  B_1
2017-07-01 00:00:00  1  34  e    9    0
2017-07-01 00:05:00  2  34  e   92    2
2017-07-01 00:10:00  3  34  e   23    3
2017-07-01 00:15:00  4  34  e    2    5
2017-07-01 00:20:00  5  34  e    4    3
```

I want to split it and concat with `axis=0`, the result like this

```
                     C  REQ  _1
2017-07-01 00:00:00  e  1    9
2017-07-01 00:05:00  e  2   92
2017-07-01 00:10:00  e  3   23
2017-07-01 00:15:00  e  4    2
2017-07-01 00:20:00  e  5    4
2017-07-01 00:00:00  e  34    0
2017-07-01 00:05:00  e  34    2
2017-07-01 00:10:00  e  34    3
2017-07-01 00:15:00  e  34    5
2017-07-01 00:20:00  e  34    3
```

So, I have to do it like this:
First, select `df[['C','A','A_1']]`, `df[['C','B', 'B_1']]`. Then map the columns, and concat the result.

It's complicated，is there any built-in method in pandas to do this? Or any faster method? Because I have thousands of columns to concat with to get the final result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## EDIT

After doing some research `lreshape` is not documented well and `pd.wide_to_long`, which is in the current API, does the same as lreshape with more flexibility.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2567

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15003

Let's use the API documented method:

```
dict1 = {'A':'REQ_A1','B':'REQ_B1','A_1':'Value_A1','B_1':'Value_B1'}

df2 = df1.rename(columns=dict1)

(pd.wide_to_long(df2.reset_index(),['REQ','Value'],i='index',j='C',sep='_',suffix='.')
  .rename_axis(['index','dropme'])
  .reset_index()
  .drop('dropme', axis=1)
  .rename(columns={'Value':'_1'}))
```

Output:

```
                 index  C  REQ  _1
0  2017-07-01 00:00:00  e    1   9
1  2017-07-01 00:05:00  e    2  92
2  2017-07-01 00:10:00  e    3  23
3  2017-07-01 00:15:00  e    4   2
4  2017-07-01 00:20:00  e    5   4
5  2017-07-01 00:00:00  e   34   0
6  2017-07-01 00:05:00  e   34   2
7  2017-07-01 00:10:00  e   34   3
8  2017-07-01 00:15:00  e   34   5
9  2017-07-01 00:20:00  e   34   3
```

---

Use `pd.lreshape`:

```
d = {'REQ': ['A', 'B'], '_1': ['A_1', 'B_1']}
df_out = (pd.lreshape(df.reset_index(), d).set_index('index'))
```

Output:

```
                     C  REQ  _1
index                          
2017-07-01 00:00:00  e    1   9
2017-07-01 00:05:00  e    2  92
2017-07-01 00:10:00  e    3  23
2017-07-01 00:15:00  e    4   2
2017-07-01 00:20:00  e    5   4
2017-07-01 00:00:00  e   34   0
2017-07-01 00:05:00  e   34   2
2017-07-01 00:10:00  e   34   3
2017-07-01 00:15:00  e   34   5
2017-07-01 00:20:00  e   34   3
```

Comment: amazing, what does lreshape do exactly? Can't find it in documentation

Comment: Yeah, it isn't documented.  However, I have seen others use it here quite a bit.  Basically, it reshapes, the dataframe based on the directory provided.

Comment: @J.Doe For `lreshape` https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/86233e15193c3bcd0f646915891ca6c7892335d9/pandas/core/reshape.py#L858
also you can check `pd.wide_to_long` should work as well .

Comment: @Wen Thanks for finding the source code / documentation.

Comment: @Wen  Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Wen FYI... I did some digging into lreshape.

Comment: @Vaishali I did some digging into lreshape  Wen is correct let's use pd.wide_to_long instead.

Comment: @J.Doe Wen is correct, let's use pd.wide_to_long instead for more robust future proofing code.  lreshape could be removed or deprecated at anytime.

Comment: @ScottBoston BTW  a downvote for my answer, let me figure out `lreshape` not safety at all, you can check here and let us update each other , when the `lreshape` deprecated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699653/using-column-name-as-a-new-attribute-in-pandas/45699937#45699937

Comment: @Wen  Yeah, I know that guy.  He is the one who taught me Pandas back in December 2016.  I asked him about why lreshape wasn't documented about two weeks ago. He told me it could be deprecated and anytime and did and encourage me to update my solution.  I think you should do the same.

Comment: @ScottBoston Working on it ~