# Data format using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda, unpivot

I am fairly new to data field, I have problem like this, here is my dataframe

```
------------------------------------------------------
ErrorCD    ID    Freq1      Freq2     Freq3....
------------------------------------------------------
1          A      2          3           2
2          B      1          2           2
3          C      1          3           3
```

And I want it be like this:

```
---------------------
ErrorCD  ID    Freq
---------------------
1        A      2
2        A      3
3        A      2
.....
```

How can do this in using python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to stack

```
df.set_index(['ErrorCD', 'ID']).stack().reset_index(name='Freq')

   ErrorCD ID level_2  Freq
0        1  A   Freq1     2
1        1  A   Freq2     3
2        1  A   Freq3     2
3        2  B   Freq1     1
4        2  B   Freq2     2
5        2  B   Freq3     2
6        3  C   Freq1     1
7        3  C   Freq2     3
8        3  C   Freq3     3
```

We can get rid of the column of `FreqX` with

```
df.set_index(['ErrorCD', 'ID']).stack().reset_index(name='Freq').drop('level_2', 1)

   ErrorCD ID  Freq
0        1  A     2
1        1  A     3
2        1  A     2
3        2  B     1
4        2  B     2
5        2  B     2
6        3  C     1
7        3  C     3
8        3  C     3
```

---

Another approach, rebuilding

```
f = df.filter(regex='^Freq')
m = f.shape[1]
pd.DataFrame(dict(
    ErrorCD=df.ErrorCD.values.repeat(m),
    ID=df.ID.values.repeat(m),
    Freq=f.values.ravel()
))

   ErrorCD  Freq ID
0        1     2  A
1        1     3  A
2        1     2  A
3        2     1  B
4        2     2  B
5        2     2  B
6        3     1  C
7        3     3  C
8        3     3  C
```

---

You can also use `pd.DataFrame.melt`

```
df.melt(['ErrorCD', 'ID'], value_name='Freq').drop('variable', 1)

   ErrorCD ID  Freq
0        1  A     2
1        2  B     1
2        3  C     1
3        1  A     3
4        2  B     2
5        3  C     3
6        1  A     2
7        2  B     2
8        3  C     3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.lreshape`

```
In [13]: pd.lreshape(df, {'Freq':df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Freq')]})
Out[13]:
   ErrorCD ID  Freq
0        1  A     2
1        2  B     1
2        3  C     1
3        1  A     3
4        2  B     2
5        3  C     3
6        1  A     2
7        2  B     2
8        3  C     3
```

sorted:

```
In [14]: pd.lreshape(df, {'Freq':df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Freq')]}) \
           .sort_values('ID')
Out[14]:
   ErrorCD ID  Freq
0        1  A     2
3        1  A     3
6        1  A     2
1        2  B     1
4        2  B     2
7        2  B     2
2        3  C     1
5        3  C     3
8        3  C     3
```

PS i couldn't find online documentation for it, but there is a good docstring:

```
In [12]: pd.lreshape?
Signature: pd.lreshape(data, groups, dropna=True, label=None)
Docstring:
Reshape long-format data to wide. Generalized inverse of DataFrame.pivot

Parameters
----------
data : DataFrame
groups : dict
    {new_name : list_of_columns}
dropna : boolean, default True

Examples
--------
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({'hr1': [514, 573], 'hr2': [545, 526],
...                      'team': ['Red Sox', 'Yankees'],
...                      'year1': [2007, 2008], 'year2': [2008, 2008]})
>>> data
   hr1  hr2     team  year1  year2
0  514  545  Red Sox   2007   2008
1  573  526  Yankees   2007   2008

>>> pd.lreshape(data, {'year': ['year1', 'year2'], 'hr': ['hr1', 'hr2']})
      team   hr  year
0  Red Sox  514  2007
1  Yankees  573  2007
2  Red Sox  545  2008
3  Yankees  526  2008

Returns
-------
reshaped : DataFrame
```

Comment: @Wen, why i shouldn't use it?

Comment: You can check it ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699653/using-column-name-as-a-new-attribute-in-pandas/45699937#45699937 , also github https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15003

Comment: @Wen, that's interesting - i didn't know that. Thanks for sharing a link

Comment: Just like `agg({'A':func})` and `.ix ` , Let us get ride of those undocumented function :-)

Answer (score 2):

By using `wide_to_long`

```
pd.wide_to_long(df,'Freq',i=['ErrorCD','ID'],j='age').reset_index().drop('age',1)
Out[445]: 
   ErrorCD ID  Freq
0        1  A     2
1        1  A     3
2        1  A     2
3        2  B     1
4        2  B     2
5        2  B     2
6        3  C     1
7        3  C     3
8        3  C     3
```